# inline-block CSS issue in webkit

Tags: css

To see the issue visit: http://justinzaun.com/LCARS/

The two css blocks in question are located at line 260 and 284 in the linked css file. Specifically its the display: inline-block on both - I think.

This looks correct in FF. I'm not sure in IE as I haven't tested it yet. In webkit (chrome and safari) it looks wrong.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Edit (added images and explanation):
[image]

[image]

The top image it from FF and it looks good. The bottom image is from webkit. Notice the 2 buttons and the label are pushed down by about 5 pixels. There is no space under the text.

Comment: IE before 8 will not allow inline-block except on elements with default display: inline.  If IE 7, etc are important to you, you may want to rethink your design entirely (yes, it's a real pain to do without inline-block).

Comment: @ysth: If I can get it to work in webkit, FF, and IE8+ I'll be happy :) IE9 should be out soon enough, having to support IE6&7 just isn't worth it any more for me. Any idea's on the webkit issue?

Comment: How do we know what it is supposed to look like? I tried the website in chrome and ff, it looks pretty much the same. Provide more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<div class="buttonbar">
    <div class="largebutton" style="float:left;display:block;">
        Label
    </div>
    <div class="button" style="float:left;display:block;">
        Label
    </div>
    <div class="label" style="float:left;display:block;">
        A label to disply text in... Fun Times...
    </div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>      
</div>
```

Or add `float:left;display:block;` to your `.largebutton`, `.button` and `.label` classes. lines (260, 284 and 308).

**UPD**: If you still want to use `inline-block` - try adding `vertical-align:top` to all 3 of your classes.

Comment: This works, and I would be OK using it, but I would like to know why inline-block doesn't work in webkit. If there is no fix posted using inline-block I'll mark this correct.

Comment: vertical-align:block doesn't do anything. thought a float:left with a display: inline-block; works. I'll stick with your original fix.

Comment: I had a typo in `vertical-align:block`, use `vertical-align:top` instead.

Comment: That does work, both fixes fix this issue. Thanks for the help